# How can spacetime change with time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, time

As far as I understand, spacetime fuses the 3 dimensions of space with the dimension of time into a single entity. If there's a big curvature, things will experience a change in how they experience time.

However, we also know that the curvature of spacetime can change, for example, in the ripples we detect in merging black holes.

My question is, how can spacetime change and experience time? Is the change of spacetime outside of spacetime itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of spacetime in terms of a 2-dimensional surface. Let the space dimension be East/West, and the time dimension be North/South.  If the surface has ripples, then the shape of *space* at any one moment in time will correspond to an East/West slice passing through just that moment in time.  If that moment "slides" Northward, the resulting East/West slice changes as the moment slides, yielding a "movie" of the ripples as they change in time.  But if you look at the whole spacetime surface including *both* space and time, it is a fixed shape.

Answer (score 1):

Spacetime doesn't change. The gravitational waves from a black hole merger are located on the future light cone of the merger. There's no earlier "meta-time" at which the spacetime is flat there.